# BadUSB tarned as Mass Storage

Tags: windows-10, badusb

Can an USB Device be infected with BadUSB if Windows recognizes an USB Device as an USB Mass Storage?

The Windows Event Log identifies the Device as `SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DT_101_G2`

How high is the risk that this USB Device is a BadUSB Device?
Malwarebytes and Avast did not recognize any malware (Full scan)

Comment: The Malware programs as of yet CAN NOT scan for BadUSB. (they damage s done before they scan anyways)

Comment: But I ran the full scan after I plugged off the usb device

Comment: The USB Stick seems to be a Kingston DT101 G2. Is the controller in this USB Stick even vulnerable by BadUSB?

Comment: Have a look at [this list](https://opensource.srlabs.de/projects/badusb), but note that the actual chip can differ, even for devices produced in the same batch, so the only way to be sure is to open the usb device and look at the make and model of the chip.

Comment: The list posted by @BadSkillz says that all Phison based USB 2.0 / 3.0 Sticks are vulnerable. But the wiki of Psychson (Source Code of BadUSB) says that only USB 3.0 Sticks with (Phison PS2251-03) are compatible. If the USB which I plugged in was a USB 2.0 Device with a different Controller, the risk to have become infected should be fairly zero?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly the point of BadUSB, at first it looks like a mass storage device, but because of the way USB operates, this function can be renegotiated. It can tell the computer it is now a keyboard, give it some commands and return to being a mass storage device.

Comment: And how can I check if the usb device acted for a short time as an keyboard? Can the Windows event log show me this?

Comment: when you log all USB HOST events, yes you can. however. the 'keyboard' can also be used to instruct windows to stop this logging and to remove the logs present (in theory, through automated scripted terminal commands)

Comment: Keep an eye out for USB devices being installed without you putting a new device in your computer, That is pretty much the only tell there is at this moment.

Comment: I sat in front of the laptop and I did not recognize any "virtual" keyboard  events. I just plugged in the USB drive, formatted it and plugged it off. 
Windows log only shows that one device has been installed.

Comment: Formatting the usb drive wil NOT fix BadUSB, if you suspect a drive to be compromised, throw it in the trash.